# Learning roadmap for classical algebraic geometry (Italian school)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, book-recommendation

Can someone suggest a learning roadmap for classical algebraic geometry as developed by the great Italian school? Severi has a few books but in Italian. I would like to know what are the best English substitutes available.

Answer (score 5):

The first reference that comes to mind is Dolgachev, *Classical Algebraic Geometry*. This uses the language of modern algebraic geometry, but tries to stick to the "Italian" point of view as far as possible. From the parts I've read, it seems like a great book.

If you want  a text in English that really uses the classical language and notation, you can try Hodge–Pedoe, *Methods of Algebraic Geometry* (3 volumes). A warning, though: if you're anything like me, this will send you running back to the modern texts.

Comment: You might also try looking at Joe Harris's *Algebraic Geometry*, which is built around lots and lots of fundamental examples and is very classical in flavor.

Comment: thanks,aside do you know how are H.F.Bakers 6 volumes? from which volume could one start reading?

Comment: Dear @K.Ghosh, I must admit I'd never heard of Baker's books before.

Comment: thanks for "dolgachev" just what i wanted

Comment: @K.Ghosh: great!